# bashでファイルの最後からxxx行目に行を追加したい

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=`/bin/grep -w '^test' /tmp/test/test.txt`
if [ "${TEST}" == "" ]; then
  #testがない場合
  echo "test" >> /tmp/test/test.txt
else
  #testがある場合
fi
```

上記でファイルの最後にtest行が追加できたのですが、
ファイルの最後からxx行目に追加するには　echo　ではできないでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo`ではできないと思います。
`sed`を使うとよいでしょう。

```sh
file='/tmp/test/test.text'

#ファイルの最後からxx行目の行番号を取得
line_num=$(grep -c ^ $file)
row_num=$((line_num - xx))

#指定行に挿入
sed -i ''$row_num'i test' $file
```

細かなところは以下を参考にしました。

- [grep -cで行数を数える時の罠](https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2017/04/20/computer-linux-mac-bash-zsh/)
- [スクリプト言語sed、awk](http://www.coins.tsukuba.ac.jp/~yas/coins/syspro-2001/2001-06-25/)
- [bashで演算を行う方法: 小粋空間](http://www.koikikukan.com/archives/2014/01/09-012345.php)

Comment: ありがとうございますsed…なるほど。大変勉強になりました。早速試したところ、やりたいことができました！

Answer (score 0):

`sed`を使うのがスマートだと私も思いますが、別解として`head`と`tail`を使う方法を挙げてみます。

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Cu
#set -vx # Uncomment for debugging

FILE="/tmp/test/test.txt"
TMPFILE="$(mktemp --tmpdir "tmp_XXXX_${0##*/}.XXXX")"
TEST=$(/bin/grep -w '^test' $FILE)

if [ "${TEST}" == "" ]; then
    #testがない場合最後から4行目に追記する
    #最終行の改行の有無によって結果が変わる点に注意する必要が有ります
    offset=4
    { 
        head --lines=$(($(wc --lines <"$FILE")-"$offset")) "$FILE"
        echo "test"
        tail --lines="$offset" "$FILE"
    } >"$TMPFILE"
    mv --force "$TMPFILE" "$FILE"
else
    #testがある場合
    : 
fi

exit $?
```

Answer (score 0):

sedで末尾行から何行目に挿入、というのは難しいですが、先頭行から何行目に挿入、というのは簡単なので一度逆転させてみました。

```sh
FILE=hoge.txt
NUM=5
tac "${FILE}" | sed "${NUM}i test" | tac
```